# Google Datastore Emulator - Spring Boot - Start Emulator In-Memory

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have a Spring App that I am boot running with the following local properties to set up a GCP Datastore Emulator:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.emulator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.datastore.host=localhost:8081
```

The application boots and connects to the datastore emulator as expected, and I am able to read/write with no problem.   However, when I try to clear the database by sending a POST request to http://localhost:8081/reset an error occurs:

> " Cannot reset a Datastore Emulator when it is storing data on
> disk.  Re-run the emulator with the --testing flag to
> start the emulator in-memory."

ok, great, I want to run in-memory locally anyway but cannot find a spring.cloud.gcp.datastore property that will configure this for me, i.e., set the --testing flag.  Searching around, I see many people start up the emulator and set their arguments using gcloud commands but I'm hoping there is a property setting to do this.

For integration testing I was able configure the in memory setting using the localdatastorehelper `LocalDatastoreHelper.newBuilder().setStoreOnDisk(false)` but I am hoping there is a better/easier way to do this when starting up the application.